# How to format cells containing errors

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have several cells containing phone numbers formatted as Text - eg: 3476225598
How can I convert each cell so that it's displayed as 347.6225598 ?

Comment: Is there an issue with errors in your data, or is that a typo in your title?

Answer (score 0):

If the cells are formatted as Text, then Select them and run this short macro:

```
Sub FormatCells()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        r.NumberFormat = "@"
        v = r.Text
        r.Value = Left(v, 3) & "." & Mid(v, 4)
    Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT #1**:

Without **VBA**, assume the data is in **A1**.....in **B1** enter:

```
=LEFT(A1,3) & "." & MID(A1,4,9999)
```

Comment: Thank you! Is possible to do the same thing without using a macro?

Comment: Yes...............see my edit

Comment: Ok, but this way I have to add another column. It's possible to do this without adding columns? (using the same column)

Comment: @WeContest You can copy the contents of the new column and then `Paste Special...` > `Values only` over the original column. Then you can delete the extra column of formulas.